# DbSet<TEntity>.Add(TEntity) and Uniqueness

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm just re-learning SQLServer after many years using .Net with other databases.

I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

I have a 1 table database in SQLServer.  From that table I have used Entity Framework to generate the model.  The table has both a primary key (autoincrement) and a unique key (the natural key on three columns of the table).

The model generated by EF has generated code for the Unique Key index:

```
        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Col1, e.Col2, e.Col3})
            .HasName("MyTable_UK")
            .IsUnique();
```

I am adding multiple rows to the DbSet using: db.MyTable.Add(myRow); without calling SaveChanges immediately.

I was expecting db.MyTable.Add(myRow); to throw an exception when the unique index was violated.  It does not; it allows duplicate rows in the DbSet.  When I SaveChanges to the Database I get the UK violation as an exception.

Is there any way to get this to throw an exception before I call SaveChanges?  It seems to have all the information required to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily write a query to check whether the record you are trying to insert already exists:

```
if (!db.MyTable.Any(e => e.Col1 == myRow.Col1 && e.Col2 == myRow.Col2 && e.Col3 == myRow.Col3))
{
     db.MyTable.Add(myRow);
}
else {
    // You can throw an exception here if you'd like but I usually prefer to return 'false' or some other indicator.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concise answer!  Makes sense to me.  Unfortunately, Any is not available for db.MyTable - I only get AnyAsync.  I have made changes to await db.MyTable.AnyAsync and made the method I am writing "async".  When I run, the program exits at the AnyAsync and no exception is throw.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer.  In my comment above .Any was not showing in intellisense because I was missing using System.Linq!!  How annoying.

Comment: One IMPORTANT amendment to this solution.  db.MyTable.Any only looks within the accepted rows.  If you are searching the DbSet before calling SaveChanges you need to use db.MyTable.Local.Any to find rows that have been added but not saved.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping `SaveChanges` to `try...catch` block is always the right&Simplest way to validate database actions.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Add(data);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException is SqlException innerException)
        {
            // handle exception here..
            ModelState.AddModelError("Col1", yourmessage1);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Col1", yourmessage2);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Col1", ex.Message);
    }
}
return View();
```

But if you do want to make things complex, here is the right way:

Let's say here is your entity

```
public class Example
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Col1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Col2 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Col3 { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}


public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Example> Examples { get; set; }


    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ValidateEntities();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void ValidateEntities()
    {
        var hasChanges = ChangeTracker.Entries()
           .Any(x => (x.Entity is Example) && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

        if (!hasChanges)
        {
            return;
        }

        var addedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
           .Where(x => (x.Entity is Example) && x.State == EntityState.Added)
           .Select(x => x.Entity as Example);

        // The tricky is right here: this.Examples.Where(...), will it execute in DB or local?
        var existingEntities = this.Examples.Where(x => addedEntries.Any(e => e.Col1 == x.Col1 && e.Col2 == x.Col2 && x.Col3 == e.Col3));

        if (existingEntities.Any())
        {
            var keys = string.Join("; ", existingEntities.Select(x => $"{x.Col1}-{x.Col2}-{x.Col3}"));

            throw new Exception($"{keys} already exist.");
        }

        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => (x.Entity is Brand) && x.State == EntityState.Modified);

        if (modifiedEntries.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        ////TO DO: the rest code for modified entries, more complex than added part.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quality, detailed code.  I learned a lot from reading it.  It doesn't really fit my case though.  I'm using MyTable DbSet like a list of unique objects that should be inserted.  Each time I create one of the objects I quickly want to know if the object is already in the DbSet,  Because, if it is I will process it differently.  Waiting until the list is full and then validating is not going achieve what I want.